# CKEditor protected tags and formatting rules

Tags: ckeditor

The formatting rules on protected tags are ignored. 
I have been able to successfully set rules on `cke-instance.dataProcessor.writer`, such as **breakBeforeOpen** and **breakAfterClose** on all sorts of tags that would otherwise do not enforce these rules.

This way I can achieve a more readable source html on content that would otherwise look like a big blob of code.

Nonetheless, whatever rule I specify on a tag that is protected, is ignored. Deprotecting the tag gives the desired result, but can't that, need to keep the item protected, and ideally allow it to breakBeforeOpen and breakAfterClose.

Do you have any suggestion as to how to achieve this in a clean and gracefully, non hacky way ? Thanks !

Agustin.